# PHP: How to increment a value in the table row to count views and to limit counts to one IP address

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ip

I'm using the following to inset a number into 'mviews' every time some map is viewed.

Question 1. Where in the following code do i add 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mviews = mviews+ 1' so it can increment on duplicate?

Question 2. How do i limit counts to one IP?

Question 3. How can i limit this IP to only increment the 'mviews' only within 24 hours; only the first view will be counted on every 24 hours, the rest of the views within 24 hours after the first view are not suppose to be counted.

```
<?php
require_once 'db_conx.php';
$result = mysql_query( "UPDATE profiles SET mviews = '1' WHERE pid = '2' ")  or die (mysql_error());
  /*ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mviews = mviews+ 1 */               
if($result){
                echo "Views + 1";
                }
                else {
                     echo "Views inser error";
                }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

is used with `INSERT` and not with `UPDATE` statement [DOCS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

count for one IP will be like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM profiles WHERE IP = "127.1.0.0";
```

[If you are not looking for what I have written above]

if IP address is your primary key then

```
INSERT INTO 
profiles (ip,views) 
VALUES ("127.1.0.0",1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE views=views+1;
```

If you want your Code to work properly[dont use mysql_* also escape user input]

```
<?php
require_once 'db_conx.php';
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE pid =2")  or die (mysql_error());
  /*ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mviews = mviews+ 1 */               
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
     mysql_query( "INSERT INTO profiles (views) value(1) ")  or die (mysql_error());
    }else {
             mysql_query( "UPDATE profiles SET mviews = mviews +1 WHERE pid = '2' ")  or die (mysql_error());
      }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I'm i not suppose to use UPDATE if that row already exists? And what about if IP is not my primary key? is this not alllowed 'ON DUPLICATE views 
UPDATE views=views+1;'?

Comment: yes you can do a select *... and check if exist and if not insert else update but this is a cleaner solution,and your current code is wrong

Answer (score 1):

To both Eustatia & Arun Killu - THANK YOU!!! Because of your posted/edited solution, I was helped out of a mind-bending jam. I have to create an addendum (as my currently-resolved situation may be of help to someone reading this).

My situation was how to establish a click-tracking process for a variable-based hyperlink (i.e.);

`<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $link;?>"><b><?php echo $title;?></b></a>`

I kept getting the link to echo out the representative information, open the correct, id-tagged link request (and not baffle user expectation of conventional click-behavior), but the ability to MULTIPLY log link clicks was solved by this post. NOTE TO THE SUPRA-FINICKY - YES! PDO IS THE DEFACTO STANDARD.

I apologize PROFUSELY for spreading the rank taint of deprecation, but if I understand what I'm doing now, I should be able to assimilate rudimentary PDO mastery in a 3 - 6 week period.

```
<?php 
/** Connect to DB */
mysql_connect("localhost","database_user","pwd") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database_name") or die(mysql_error()); 

$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

/** retrieve URL */
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE ID = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());

/*ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clicks = clicks+ 1 */               
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `articles`(`clicks`) value(1)")  or die (mysql_error());
}else {
         mysql_query("UPDATE `articles` SET clicks=clicks+1 WHERE `id` = '$id'")  or die (mysql_error());
  }
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
mysql_close();

header("Location: " . $row['link']);
?>
```

I ended up changing the configuration of the link so the id passed the correct link to the target page;

`<?php echo "<a href='pagetracking.php?id=" . $id . $link . "' target='_blank'>
<font color='#0000CC' size='5'><b>" . $row['title']. "</b></font></a>"; ?>`

Thank you SO MUCH for posting Eustatia & Arun Killu, I really appreciate the tip. If anyone else here happening across this sees anything that's EXCEPTIONALLY unforgivable (even in this decrepit state, lol) - PLEASE, do - not - hesitate - to scream on it robustly. I need all the help I can get.

Comment: To whoever gave me the point vote, I thank you kindly (did not expect that, lol!), but I need to add a note to the overall coding -to ensure all clicks are registered, set the default to `not null` for the clicks column, and define it as 0. Some of my link clicks were recorded and some weren't. This change ENSURES that each click for each link is incremented +1. Now, to get to work absorbing PDO...

Comment: I've already figured out and implemented this in PDO - will be posting as soon as I have a spare millisecond (lol!)

Answer (score 0):

As promised for anyone who'd be in need of a **WORKING** version of this in PDO;
(this is adapted from an answer that I found here on SO, but, can't remember at the second, so I'll look it up for an edit to give the answerer credit.)

**track.php**

```
<?php
    //Your database information
   include '../includes/db.php';

// Fetch id (article_id) from $_GET parameter
$article_id = '';
if (isset($_GET['id'])) $article_id = intval($_GET['id']);

if (!$article_id) {
  print "No article ID found!\n";
} else {

   //
   // Fetch Article ID
   //
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE article_id = :article_id";
  $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $sth->bindParam(":article_id", $article_id);
  $sth->execute();
}

if (!$sth) {
// No article!
  echo 'Invalid Article ID!\n';
 } else {
// Article found!
   //
   // Update Clicks Column
   //
   $sql = "UPDATE articles SET clicks=clicks+1 WHERE article_id = :article_id";
   $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $sth->bindParam(':article_id', $article_id);
   $sth->execute();
}
header('Location: view_article.php?id='.intval($_GET['id']));
?>
```

As this code is working flawlessly, **for MY purposes**, here's a little caveat for those looking to just blindly cut-and-paste...it updates the `clicks` column ***EACH TIME IT'S CLICKED***, soooooo if you need to limit it to a certain amount of clicks or some other type of functionality, I wish you well in your endeavors (lol!). I just wanted to publish this as a current, working model of the PDO kind. In fact, I may have to end up using this solution as a basis of another mind-bending jam I'm in right now. In fact, I'm almost willing to bet dollars to donuts I'll be completely right about this move.

**HTHSO**

P.S. ...PDO is sooooooo **annoyingly** difficult...but worth it.