# codeigniter url link returns same article text regardless of article id

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've tried to crab from another question asked before at
    [link going through tracking script pulls correct article id, incorrect article text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483025/link-going-through-tracking-script-pulls-correct-article-id-incorrect-article-t)
, but, alas, no love. I'm no stranger to the CI 3x docs, but I haven't found anything to help me with this and I suspect there may be more than one issue at play here. I've made sure that the appropriate libraries, helpers, and models are all previously included through the autoloader. The issue is the same as in the previously-mentioned article; the article id URLs are all perfect as far as referencing the correct id. However, the same text is being returned no matter which article link is clicked upon.

I'm accessing the article view page (and passing in the id variable) from my controller like so;

**Articlelist.php**

```
public function view($id)
{
    $this->load->view('view_article');
}
```

In the referenced view, there's a query that's supposed to return a single article text by its' id;

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

and then I'm able to use **$query->result()** in a **foreach** loop to access my content elements. I'm returning these results through two different pages and the reader is able to click on a link to navigate with;

```
echo '<a href="articlelist/view/id='.intval($row->article_id).'">  
<font size="5" color="#0000CC">Click Here To View Article</font></a><hr>';
```

I actually tried to append **?id='.intval($_GET['id'])** to the view page (view_article.php) previously, but was left with a messy error trail. I even tried as last-ditch rewrites;

```
$query_str="SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_id DESC LIMIT 1";
$query=$this->db->query($query_str);
 // fetch one row data
 $record=$query->row();
 echo $record->title;
 echo $record->name;
 echo $record->date;
 echo $record->category;
 echo $record->article_text;

===================================================================

$query = $this->db->get('articles, 0, 1);
foreach($query->result() as $row) {
  echo '<font face="arial black" color="#0000CC" size="5">Title:&nbsp;' .$row->title. '</font>' .'<br />';
  echo '<font face="arial black" color="#0000CC" size="5">Publisher:&nbsp;' .$row->name. '</font>' .'<br />'; 
  echo '<font face="arial black" color="#0000CC" size="5">Category:&nbsp;' .$row->category. '</font>' .'<br />';
  echo '<font face="arial black" color="#0000CC" size="5">Published:&nbsp;' .$row->date. '</font>' .'<br />';
  echo '<font face="arial black" color="#0000CC" size="5">Content:<br />' .$row->article_text. '</font>' .'<br />';
}
```

but, I'm still left with the issue of the incorrect article text being returned under the correct article id. I even tried to ascertain that it wasn't a matter of routing by setting a baseline catch-all;

```
$route['(:num)/(:any)']='articlelist/view/id/$1';
```

I'm almost where I want to be as article content is being returned when items on the articlelist page are clicked upon, but what am I missing in order to connect to the correct article id? If any other information is needed for an assessment, please request it, thanks.

**UPDATE**

I went back and connected a model process to the view page as it was missing;

```
public function view($id)
{
    $data['results'] = $this->article_model->getArticle($id);
    $this->load->view('view_article', $data);
}
```

but it added nothing by the way of a resolution and was redacted shortly thereafter.

**UPDATE 2**

Thanks to @JefreN & @cr05s19xx for their answers - let me add how the model and the relevant controller code is;

**Article_model.php**

```
 function getArticle($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*')->order_by('article_id', 'desc')->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_id DESC LIMIT 1");
    return $query->result();

}
```

**Articlelist.php**

```
public function view($id)
{
    $data['results'] = $this->article_model->getArticle($id);
    $this->load->view('view_article', $data);
}
```

Even with the updates applied, I'm still only getting the content from the URL

```
http://localhost/articlelist/view/id=33
```

**no matter which article link I click on**.

Comment: Can you get the correct id of the page you are supposed to be getting?

Comment: @JefréN. - **THAT** is the crux of my dilemma - no matter WHICH article link I click, the only text that is returned is from the last id in the database. Strange...

Comment: Are you using a `new mysqli()` object?

Comment: No mysqli - even go so far as to hardcode the MySQL value in my config file.

Comment: Sorry about the past poor code--learning the lesson of getting all information *before* writing an answer. (I should have looked at it better.) I've one more attempt that you can try,  you have any more patience. :DD

Comment: Deleted my answer ... if you're interested in any other conversation, we can chat [here.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115775/discussion-between-jefre-n-and-homeoffice) (I'll be going to bed soon, but definitely want you to get your problem solved.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, it started poking at me that in the page where the pagination results were being returned, there was no on-page query. **THAT** job, being taken care of in the **article_model.php** file. Deciding to do a little creative re-arrangement;

```
function getArticle($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')->get_where('articles', array('article_id' => $id));
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
           $data[] = $row;
        }
           return $data;    
    }

}
```

After that, it was only a hop, skip, and a jump to the realization of the elimination of the other link-point on-page query, so I could switch to working code in the controller to eliminate my issue;

```
public function view($id)
{
    $data = array();
    $data['results'] = $this->article_model->getArticle($id);
    $this->load->view('view_article', $data);
}
```

aaaaaaaaannnnnnnnndd...having solved this problem led to the pagination being all borked.

For anyone in the future having this problem; CodeIgniter documentation stipulates that pages (being represented via the URI segments) are of the format;

```
http://domain(.*)/controller/method/arguments
```

On the 1st page of returned pagination results, the URI given when hovering over each result;

```
http://localhost  /articlelist  /view     /33 
       (domain)   (controller)  (method)  (arguments)
```

However, from the second to the last page of pagination results, there was an EXTRA segment;

```
http://localhost  /articlelist  /index    /view     /33 
       (domain)   (controller)  (?????)   (method)  (arguments)
```

because of the **$config['base_url'] = site_url('articlelist/index');** - needed to keep the pagination results corralled in place for display.

This was corrected by correcting the borky part of the view page listing the db query results (articles_list.php);

```
echo '<h3><a title="Click Here For Content" href="'?>
<?php echo base_url().'articlelist/view/'.$row->article_id.'">
'. $row->title. '</a></h3><hr>';
```

(probably should bother to point out that the last opening php tag is closed further down in code not quoted on-page for those seeing this as a solution candidate)

Thanks to all who threw their $0.02 out there for consideration - helped me find my answer. Tested over 10 selections from the two link-point areas, and pulled the **CORRECT** article content to match the article id URL in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see with your URL given,

> Even with the updates applied, I'm still only getting the content from
>   the URL
>
> http://localhost/articlelist/view/id=33 no matter which article link I
>   click on.

You should only pass the `33` as id directly next to the `view` method.
See below:

```
http://localhost/articlelist/view/33
```

This then calls your `ariclelist->view` method.

```
public function view($id) { ... }
```

Model query can also be written in this option using the codeigniter prepared methods.

```
public function get_article_info($id) 
{
    $this->db->select()->from('articles')->where('article_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array(); 
}
```

See more on [Generating Query Results - CodeIgniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html) .

Comment: Thank you so much for your response @Joseph Dicdican but your attempt was unsuccessful. It DID allow me to neaten up the coding by reducing it a few lines, though.

Comment: You're welcome @HomeOffice .. But result_array should return an empty array or array of your article like 
`$data['result'] = array(
   [0] => array(
          'article_id' => 1,
          ....
      )
)` but nevertheless, you solved it already..

Answer (score 1):

The correct query is `SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id = $id`

In Codeigniter a model would have been written like this

```
<?php
defined ('BASEPATH') or exit ('No direct script access allowed');

class Example_model extends CI_Model {

    public function get_article_info($id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `article_id` = '$id'");
    // Rest of the code comes here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @cr05s19xx, but after plugging your query into my model, I got **Message: Undefined variable: id**.

Comment: Remember to pass the ID value into the model. So in the controller you would have written something like `$this->load->model('Example_model')` and also `$this->Example_model->get_article_info($id)` where $id is from the view's $id parameter you passed

Comment: please see updated question where the $id is passed in - I left out the model loading line as I used the autoloader as mentioned at the top of my question. Thanks again.